# Intermediate XML file of NED-XML

Tags: json, xml, omnet++

I am trying to insert one JSON configuration file to create a network in omnet++ through an API. I have converted the JSON to XML but unable to do the validation. If I can find out the intermediate Xml file omnet++ creates from the Ned file I can do crosscheck.Is there any way to write out the intermediate xml file created by omnet++ during simulation?
`

```
 "nodes":[
      {
         "attr":{
            "Name":"s1",
            "IP Address":"192.168.0.0",
            "Enabled System Capabilities":"none"
         },
         "Ports":[
            {
               "Identifier":"eth0",
               "Type":"6",
               "MTU":"1500",
               "Speed":"1000",
               "Physical Address":"00:00:08:19:en:ek:ff:dw",

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `opp_nedtool` allows you to convert between NEDXML and NED format. If you can convert your JSON file to NEDXML, that file can be further converted to NED which in turn can be read by the simulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I would like to know is there any difference between NEDXML and XML?
If I want to write out the NEDXML on my disk of the Tictok tutorial is it possible?

Comment: NEDXML is an XML file adhering to a specific DTD (look in doc/etc/ned2.dtd) https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:ned-xml-binding